# Is my implementation of stochastic gradient descent correct?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to develop stochastic gradient descent, but I don't know if it is 100% correct.

- The cost generated by my stochastic gradient descent algorithm is sometimes very far from the one generated by FMINUC or Batch gradient descent.
- while batch gradient descent cost converge when I set a learning rate alpha of 0.2, I am forced to set a learning rate alpha of 0.0001 for my stochastic implementation for it not to diverge. Is this normal?

Here are some results I obtained with a training set of 10,000 elements and num_iter = 100 or 500

```
    FMINUC : 
    Iteration  #100 | Cost: 5.147056e-001

    BACTH GRADIENT DESCENT  500 ITER
    Iteration #500 - Cost = 5.535241e-001

    STOCHASTIC GRADIENT DESCENT 100 ITER
    Iteration #100 - Cost = 5.683117e-001  % First time I launched
    Iteration #100 - Cost = 7.047196e-001  % Second time I launched
```

**Gradient descent implementation for logistic regression**

```
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1); 

for iter = 1:num_iters 

    [J, gradJ] = lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, lambda);
    theta = theta - alpha * gradJ;
    J_history(iter) = J;

    fprintf('Iteration #%d - Cost = %d... \r\n',iter, J_history(iter));
end
```

**Stochastic gradient descent implementation for logistic regression**

```
% number of training examples
m = length(y);

% STEP1 : we shuffle the data
data = [y, X];
data = data(randperm(size(data,1)),:);
y = data(:,1);
X = data(:,2:end);

for iter = 1:num_iters 

     for i = 1:m
        x = X(i,:); % Select one example
        [J, gradJ] = lrCostFunction(theta, x, y(i,:), lambda);
        theta = theta - alpha * gradJ;
     end

     J_history(iter) = J;
     fprintf('Iteration #%d - Cost = %d... \r\n',iter, J);

end
```

*For reference, here is the logistic regression cost function used in my example*

```
function [J, grad] = lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, lambda)

m = length(y); % number of training examples

% We calculate J    
hypothesis = sigmoid(X*theta); 
costFun = (-y.*log(hypothesis) - (1-y).*log(1-hypothesis));    
J = (1/m) * sum(costFun) + (lambda/(2*m))*sum(theta(2:length(theta)).^2);

% We calculate grad using the partial derivatives
beta = (hypothesis-y); 
grad = (1/m)*(X'*beta);
temp = theta;  
temp(1) = 0;   % because we don't add anything for j = 0  
grad = grad + (lambda/m)*temp; 
grad = grad(:);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much ok. If you are worried about choosing the appropriate learning rate `alpha`, you should think about applying a **line search** method.

Line search is a method which chooses an optimal learning rate for gradient descent at every iteration, which is better than using fixed learning rate throughout the whole optimization process. Optimal value for learning rate `alpha` is one which locally (from current `theta` in the direction of the negative gradient) minimizes cost function.

At each iteration of the gradient descent, start from the learning rate `alpha = 0` and gradually increase `alpha` by the fixed step `deltaAlpha = 0.01`, for example. Recalculate parameters `theta` and evaluate the cost function. Since the cost function is convex, by increasing `alpha` (that is, by moving in the direction of negative gradient) cost function will first start decreasing and then (at some moment) increasing. At that moment stop the line search and take the last `alpha` before cost function started increasing. Now update the parameters `theta` with that `alpha`. In case that the cost function never starts increasing, stop at `alpha = 1`.

**Note:** For big regularization factors (`lambda = 100`, `lambda = 1000`) it is possible that `deltaAlpha` is too big and that gradient descent diverges. If that is the case, decrease `deltaAlpha` 10 times (`deltaAlpha = 0.001`, `deltaAlpha = 0.0001`) until you get to the appropriate `deltaAlpha` for which gradient descent converges.

Also, you should think about using some terminating condition other than the number of iterations, e.g. when difference between cost functions in two subsequent iterations becomes small enough (less than some `epsilon`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason for small value of the learning rate.  Briefly, when the learning rates  decrease with an appropriate rate, and subject to relatively mild assumptions, stochastic gradient descent converges almost surely to a **global minimum** when the objective function is **convex** or **pseudoconvex**, and otherwise converges almost surely to a **local minimum**. This is in fact a consequence of the **Robbins-Siegmund** theorem.

> Robbins, Herbert; Siegmund, David O. (1971). "A convergence theorem
>   for non negative almost supermartingales and some applications". In
>   Rustagi, Jagdish S. Optimizing Methods in Statistics. Academic Press

Comment: What I understand if that if the learning rate is fixed, then the cost will "oscillate" around the global minimum but never reach it. That's why if we decrease the learning rate at a fixed rate, for instance by multiplying it by 0.8 , then the algorithm will oscillate less and less and eventually reach a value very close to the minimum.

Comment: yeah you are right. What I said happens when you use a fixed learning rate.

Answer (score -1):

The learning rate is always between 0 to 1. If you set the learning rate very high then it follows the desired to a lesser extent, because of skipping. So take a small learning rate even though it takes more time. The output result will be more convincing.